# retrieving the entire row in the database grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a table called 'District' in my database:

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | version | description | homepage | logo | name                                           | region_id |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

so, on my controller i have:

```
def show = {
        def districtInstance = District.get(params?.id)
        println districtInstance
        println params
        if(!districtInstance){
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'district.label', default: 'District'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action : "list", params?.id)
        }
        else{
            [districtInstance : districtInstance]
        }
    }
```

While I'm expecting to see the full row:

```
| 71 |       0 | bogus  |          |      | bogus                                      |         4 |
```

I only see:

```
bogus
```

on the console. How can I have access to the entire row? (Specially `districtInstance.region_id`? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
println districtInstance?.region.id
```

In Groovy, and object oriented languages in general, you can to *navegate* class properties like that, but you should are aware of the [Law of Demeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163071/coupling-cohesion-and-the-law-of-demeter)

Comment: Yuck. That lazily loads the _entire_ Region just to get its id.

Answer (score 2):

`println districtInstance` only prints the output of the `toString()` method. Use `println districtInstance?.dump()` to see more output including all of the class fields. It won't look like the database view however, since it's a Groovy object, not a database query result.

Update based on question: If you need the region_id, you can get it via `districtInstance.regionId` which doesn't require an extra database call.